# Run Debug Builds on iOS 9 Device with iOS 8 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios9, appcode

It there any reproducible way to run a debug build compiled with iOS 8 SDK on an iOS 9 device?

Xcode usually tells me that the device's iOS is not supported by that version of Xcode. BUT I have managed to run on the same device with the same SDK via AppCode - unfortunately it does not work everytime, but in very rare cases. In these cases even break points worked fine.
Also when distributing an app for testing, it is no problem to install an app built with the iOS 8 SDK on a device running iOS 9.

So how can we properly debug that case?

Answer (score 1):

So here's a hack that works for my whole team (I agree that it's annoying and frustrating, until you move to Xcode 7)

1. Make sure you have Xcode 7.x and Xcode 6.x Installed
2. Open Xcode 7 and let it Copy Symbols + Process Symbols so you can build the app for the device (Can take very long for new devices)
3. Open Xcode 6.4 and you'll see the iPhone. If Build fails Clean first (Cmd + K) and then run again

Known issue, 
 - It can sometimes say "Unavailable" or "OS Version" (can't be mounted because it's running on iOS 9).

```
 Fix - Quit both Xcode's. Run Xcode 7 first, let it detect the phone and then open Xcode 6.4 and you can run the app now.
```

FYI: Sometimes just disconnecting and reconnecting the iPhone makes it discover. Also, it takes a looong time to Copy/Process symbols on new phones. The process is faster on known/previous devices. 
You have to play with it for a while to figure it out. Best fix is to move to Xcode 7 ASAP.

Everything works just fine, including running on both iOS 8 and iOS 9 devices, breakpoints + debugging, and also submitting the app to iTunes connect.